# Why isnt it deleting the string from the list but it does delete something

Tags: c#, list, loops, foreach

So I have no idea why it's not deleting the actual string from the WebsiteList, it's weird because it does delete from the ProxyList.

When debugging it says that it does delete something because the websiteList.Count gets lower after running through webisteList.Remove(website);
But it doesnt delete the string, it keeps looping through the same string.

```
foreach (var website in websiteList.ToArray())
{
    var webSplit = website.Split(')');

    foreach (var proxy in proxyList.ToArray())
    {
        if (proxyList.Count > 0)
        {
            if(websiteList.Count > 0)
            {
                var proxySplit = proxy.Split(':');
                int Port;
                bool convert = Int32.TryParse(proxySplit[1], out Port);

                if (this returns true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Removing proxy");
                    proxyList.Remove(proxy);
                    websiteList.Remove(website);

                }
                if (this returns true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Removing proxy");
                    proxyList.Remove(proxy);
                    websiteList.Remove(website);
                }
            }
        }
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your actual code. `if (this returns true)` isn't valid C#. If your problem is that deleting an item from `websiteList` doesn't also delete it from the temporary array object that you're iterating through, go back and think again about why you're calling `ToArray()` in the first place. That is, assuming you know why you're calling `ToArray()` at all.

Comment: Cannot modify the List in the loop.

Comment: Further, you're doing the same thing in both your if blocks (assuming your 'this returns true' bit is just proxy code or something). Repeating code in this manner is bad. Combine both checks into a single if statement with || to run both checks.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: `ToArray()` makes sense since you cannot modify the very collection you are enumerating. Like this you enumerate the array but remove from the list.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I know why he’s calling ToArray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are repeatedly deleting from the same `proxyList` (i.e. you are repeating the whole inner loop as many times as there are websites). Why are those 2 loops nested? The websites seem not to be related to the proxies. Only if the proxy list would be extracted from a website, nesting would make sense.

Are these 2 lists supposed to have the same length and to have proxies belonging to websites at the same index? If this is the case, loop using a `for`-loop and loop in reverse order to avoid messing up the indexes.

```
for (int i = websiteList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (<condition>) {
        proxyList.RemoveAt(i);
        websiteList.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

If you had a class for the websites, this would simplify manipulating things belonging together. It also has the advantage that you can add additional logic belonging to websites and proxies (like extracting the port number):

```
public class Website
{
    public string Site { get; set; }
    public string Proxy { get; set; }

    public int Port {
        get {
            string[] proxySplit = proxy.Split(':');
            int portNo = 0;
            if (proxySplit.Length == 2) {
                Int32.TryParse(proxySplit[1], out portNo);
            }
            return portNo;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the list is of type `List<Website>` and contains both, the websites and the proxies

You can delete by using the for loop as before or use LINQ and create a new list containing only the desired items

```
websiteList = websiteList.Where(w => <condition using w.Site, w.Proxy, w.Port>).ToList();
```

Note: There is a [`System.Uri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) class for the manipulation of uniform resource identifiers. Among other things it can extract the port number. Consider using this class instead of your own.